# Largest cricket ground by length of boundary

Tags: cricket, trivia, venues

Which is the largest cricket ground by **length of boundary** in the world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Melbourne Cricket Ground is the largest cricket ground by area. The playing area in the  MCG is **172.9m x 147.8m**. If we consider the boundary length of the cricket ground, ICC stated about this in the [playing conditions](http://www.cricketromania.com/index.php?mact=News,cntnt01,print,0&cntnt01articleid=289&cntnt01showtemplate=false&cntnt01returnid=76&hl=en) that,

> In all cases the aim shall be to provide the largest playing area,
>   subject to no boundary exceeding 90 yards (82.29 meters) from the
>   centre of the pitch to be used.

So, the largest boundary length a cricket ground can have is 82.29 meters. The boundary line should be located according to that.